# Execl source to OLE DB destination

Tags: sql-server, ssis

When I'm trying to load data from Excel to SQL server(OLEDB), blank space in the EXCEL sheet is treated as Null, but I need Blank space itself. [It is the excel data, In the third row 4th column there is space, not NULL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4BDr.png)

[After creating Excel connection manager when I preview data, I discover that 3rd row fourth column is treated as NULL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOish.png)

Comment: You can view this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313286/sql-server-replace-empty-cells-with-null-value

Answer (score 1):

So run an UPDATE after the load to replace NULLs with a blank space.

Or use a Derived Column Transformation that replaces NULL with a blank space if you want to do it in the dataflow.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't want null value for blank space but i want NULL value where nothing(not a blank space itself) is there in the excel sheet.   So i don't want to replace/update all the null value. are there any way to do that?

Comment: Yes, the techniques in my answer can be used to replace anything with anything.   I'm not sure what you mean when you say "blank space" any more.   I thought you meant empty string, but to me that's the same as "nothing", so I don't know what the difference is.

Comment: yes Tab, you are correct but according to my project blank space(a normal space character ) is needed to be separated from a NULL character. Am i able to clarify the scenario?

Comment: Yes you can specify a blank space character in an UPDATE statement like this   `' '`, or in the SSIS dataflow you would use `" "`